# Unity - idea on how to move camera like transform axis in scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my camera to move around the target from a distance. Switching views from top view like a bird eye view and to switch to side way view of target.

The same way you can move around the scene ui using these transform axis.

[image: view1]

[image: view2]

I kind of have a idea for the top view, maybe point my camera at target. Add Camera offset position of 200. Increase Y point to be on top of object and 0 to X so it is centered. Making a bird eye view. And for the side way view, I would change the camera Y to 0 and X to be away from target.

Am I being clear, or do I not make sense?

Comment: And where is the code of what you have tried so far? Note that StackOverlow is for asking questions about a specific implementation issue, not for requesting complete solutions...

Comment: Not 100% clear here so I'm putting a comment instead of an answer. A lot of what I'm reading is similar to what I have done in my game other than toggling between top and side view. Two options include making separate cameras for each view and then toggling active/inactive based on when you want to use one or the other. As for offset, I think if the offset will not change dynamically in the game you can simply adjust the position of each gameobject. If it does change dynamically that's just a simple script but not enough info on how you want it to change to help.

Comment: If top is not always vector.up then you would need a script that tracks the rotation of relevant object and does a smooth transition towards it's intended rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you set the camera as a child of the player or target. After doing this I would recommend that you put the camera up above the target(set the same X and Z) and they the Y however high above you want it then angle it down towards the target, make sure to save these coordinates and this quaternion for further reference, it should follow around the target as it is a child and as long as the object does not rotate around like a circle than it should be no problem (let me know if its a circle) sorry if I misinterpreted what you said.

```
bool topView = true
public Camera cam;
void SwapCamera()
{
    if(topView)
        topView = false
        // cam.transform = new Vector3(blah blah blah)
    else
        topView = true
        // (for side cam) cam.transform = new Vector3(blah blah blah)
}
```

So sorry if I misinterpreted my guy please let me know if I was wrong so that I can assist you

Comment: For more complicated games I found that putting the camera as a child can lead to jittering graphics. So If it's simple and you don't have lots of UI then that's fine. However, after doing some debugging for some time I realized that switching the camera to 'overlay' mode instead was better.
In that case, you will probably want the camera to have a mono script that keeps track of the target's rotation and adjusts accordingly (if that is part of the requirement).

Comment: Right, one of thee things I did was using a script that logs the targets X,Z and adjusts accordingly but yeah I totally agree with the child thing, especially when using circles because it rotates the camera with the circle so yeah I think that setting it as a child would be unnecessary